# I have images in directory. have to get that image and convert into base64 string?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

How to get image from directory then convert it into base64string and send it through web service.

Comment: can you show something what already you tried

Comment: This question is much too vague. Need some code which you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
// Gets image from your file directory
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"path/to/your/directory"];
// Converts it to NSData type.
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
// Converts it to base64 string.
NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64Encoding];



// Swift 

var image: UIImage = UIImage.imageWithContentsOfFile("path/to/your/directory")!
    // Converts it to NSData type.
var imageData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
    // Converts it to base64 string.
var encodedString: String = imageData.base64Encoding()
```

Comment: The question has the tags 'swift' and 'swift2'; you might consider changing your answer's code to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I have added all three scenarios (The three examples are not related at all)
1. Converting the image.
2. Finding the image from the files directory 
3. Posting the image on the server

Here is how you create a base64 image

```
//Use image name from bundle to create NSData
let image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"imageNameHere")!
//Now use image to create into NSData format
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!

//OR next possibility

//Use image's path to create NSData
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string : "urlHere")!
//Now use image to create into NSData format
let imageData:NSData = NSData.init(contentsOfURL: url)!
```

Here is how you find the image from the file manager

```
NSString *searchFilename = @"hello.png"; // name of the PDF you are searching for

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:documentsDirectory];

NSString *documentsSubpath;
while (documentsSubpath = [direnum nextObject])
{
  if (![documentsSubpath.lastPathComponent isEqual:searchFilename]) {
    continue;
  }

  NSLog(@"found %@", documentsSubpath);
}
```

To send the request, I used NSMutableURLRequest to handle the JSON request

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url))
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

To prepare the HTTPBody, I had to encode the image to a Base64 string. This is done through the following:

```
var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9)
var base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!) // encode the image
```

After doing this, I’ve put the encoded image into a Dictionary in the appropriate parameter. I serialized it into a JSON representation which I assigned to the HTTPBody.

```
var err: NSError? = nil
var params = ["image":[ "content_type": "image/jpeg", "filename":"test.jpg", "file_data": base64String]]
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(0), error: &err)!
```

I used the shared session object to create a task to send the request. I created a request model that I can convert to a MutableURLRequest. You can see how it looks like here.

```
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request.toMutableURLRequest(), completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
    var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var err: NSError?

    // process the response
})

task.resume() // this is needed to start the task
```

After the request has completed, the block I passed via the completionHandler will be executed. From there, I was able to evaluate the response. So that’s how I was able to send the image taken from my phone’s camera to the server.